# How to change the colors value from theme.xml?

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, themes

I'm creating different themes for my application for different users and each one of them wants differents colors.

So, I have some defined groups of colors in my colors.xml and what I want to do is to change the value of those colors from my xml themes.

Right now I have the color.xml:

[image]

And then I have my theme.xml:

[image]

And what I'm doing to reach out to each one of the value name is declare them on attrs:

[image]

But it doesn't seem to work when I change the theme of the app in the manifest, so how can I change the colors value but not the name from my theme.xml.

Comment: How do you use this attr in your layouts and drawable?

Comment: for example if you want to set color of a text view you should do something like this: android:textColor="?blue_dark"

Comment: @Mohammad Bahadori yes, thats correct. But it doesn't work, the colors are maintaining their value from colors. and not from the specific theme.xml

Comment: So I think your problem is your setting theme strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

to set theme.

Comment: Pay attention, call setTheme() befor super.onCreate